# legend for multiple externalized tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, cross-referencing, tikz-external, legend

I need to externalize the two tikz images inside the code below as PDF (for a journal article) and then read these PDFs, as well as add a single legend for both from outside by using `\pgfplotslegendfromname{named}`. Externalizing the tikz images is easy, but referencing to the legend settings defined in the first tikz seems to be complex.

An alternative is to generate a PDF of the complete figure and then trim it, but I wanted to avoid that.

Can anyone please give me a help?

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.495\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[%
  scale=0.9,
  xlabel={A},
  xmajorgrids,
  ylabel={B},
  ymajorgrids,
  axis background/.style={fill=white},
  legend style={text=black, legend cell align=left,legend columns=3,/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}},
  legend to name=named]
\addplot [color=black,loosely dashed,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{1.txt};
\addplot [color=black,loosely dotted,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{2.txt};
\addplot [color=black,loosely dashdotted,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{3.txt};
\addplot [color=black,dashed,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{4.txt};
\addplot [color=black,dotted,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{5.txt};    
\addplot [color=black,dashdotted,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{6.txt};  
\addplot [color=black,densely dashed,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{7.txt};  
\addplot [color=black,densely dotted,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{8.txt};  
\addplot [color=black,densely dashdotted,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{9.txt};      
\addlegendentry{$10\%$}
\addlegendentry{$20\%$}
\addlegendentry{$30\%$}
\addlegendentry{$40\%$}
\addlegendentry{$50\%$}
\addlegendentry{$60\%$}
\addlegendentry{$70\%$}
\addlegendentry{$80\%$}
\addlegendentry{$90\%$}
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Case 1\label{fig:6a}}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.495\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{loglogaxis}[%
  scale=0.9,
  xlabel={A},
  xmajorgrids,
  ylabel={B},
  ymajorgrids,
  axis background/.style={fill=white}]
\addplot [color=black,loosely dashed,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=13]{1.txt};
\addplot [color=black,loosely dotted,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=13]{2.txt};
\addplot [color=black,loosely dashdotted,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=13]{3.txt};
\addplot [color=black,dashed,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=13]{4.txt};
\addplot [color=black,dotted,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=13]{5.txt};    
\addplot [color=black,dashdotted,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=13]{6.txt};  
\addplot [color=black,densely dashed,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=13]{7.txt};  
\addplot [color=black,densely dotted,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=13]{8.txt};  
\addplot [color=black,densely dashdotted,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=13]{9.txt};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Case 2\label{fig:6b}}
\end{subfigure}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\\
\pgfplotslegendfromname{named}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this works perfectly fine.

Please note that I have substantially simplified your code (which anyway was not compilable for us, because we don't have your table files), but should show the principle how it should also work for your code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        % use the one from PGFPlots which is more recent than the one from tikz
        pgfplots.external,
    }
    % put all externalized images in a "special" folder
    \tikzsetexternalprefix{Pics/pgf-export/}
    % enable externalization
    \tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
% (I prefer to give the images reasonable names)
\tikzsetnextfilename{first}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        xlabel={A},
        ylabel={B},
        legend to name=named,
    ]
        \addplot+ [domain=1:10] {x};
        \addlegendentry{$10\%$}
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzsetnextfilename{second}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        xlabel={A},
        ylabel={B},
    ]
        \addplot+ [domain=1:10] {1/x};
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

    % (you can also name this image, if you want to)
    \tikzsetnextfilename{first-legend}
    \pgfplotslegendfromname{named}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan! As far as I see, we can now externalize the legend itself as a PDF. In theory, I just have to read it from outside as plot. Haven't tried out with my code, but it should work fine. Also, by the way, I have another related question: is there such an automated externalization solution for multiple .svg files? Right now I'm using trimming as a temporary solution. I know about the .svg package, but it can't externalize multiple figures. Plus, even if I use -z -D, it still exports the full page, which is why I'm using trimming. Could you help with this one too?

Comment: So far I never did something with SVG, but if you ask another question here on TeX.SX and add a link here in the comments I can have a look at this as well. But please, make it really an MWE (not as you did for this question). Thus, it should be full compilable code without using `\tikzexternal`.

Comment: @user165074, any news here?

Comment: @StefanPinnow what is the advantage of using `\pgfplotslegendfromname` (which I couldn't find in the documentation) over `\ref` which seems to be mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: @StefanPinnow 

Addendum: Actually my `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.code.tex` says
`
% this is deprecated. Use \ref{#1} instead.
\def\pgfplotslegendfromname#1{%
        \pgfplots@texdist@protect\pgfplotslegendfromname@{#1}%
}%
....
`

Comment: @bonanza, I didn't say that `\pgfplotslegendfromname` is advantageous to `\ref`. I just stated that OPs code works perfectly fine, who used this command. But you are right, using `\ref` would work fine, too. The command can still be found in the manual, see [pgfplots manual section 4.9.7 on page 268 (v1.16)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=268).