# \label and \ref do not work correctly using pgfplots, hyperref and tikz externalization

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, hyperref, tikz-external, externalize

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/mode=list and make}
\tikzexternalize
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot+ coordinates {
      (1, 9) (2, 6) (3, 1) (4, 4)
    }; \label{important}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\Blindtext
Here I want to reference the plot \ref{important}.

\end{document}
```

If I comment out `\tikzexternalize` to deactivate externalization, the link generated by `\ref` points to page 2. With `\tikzexternalize` in place, it incorrectly links to page 1. I use the `latex` command that calls `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)`. I have pgfplots 1.16 installed in `~/texmf`. Note that I go through to the `make -f test.makefile` sequence required by TikZ's `list and make` externalization mode.

Comment: I think your question is the same as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436396/121799).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no destination from the label if you include an externally generated pdf. You could try something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/mode=list and make}
\tikzexternalize
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext
\hypertarget{importantdest}{}\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot+ coordinates {
      (1, 9) (2, 6) (3, 1) (4, 4)
    }; \label{important}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\Blindtext
Here I want to reference the plot \hyperlink{importantdest}{\ref*{important}}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I suppose I can just use `\ref*{important}` for the reference without a link? (I actually mostly need the plot symbol to create a custom legend in my actual document)

Comment: please note that `\ref` behaves somewhat differently in `pgfplots`. It produces a plot symbol, exactly like the legend image.