# A mess of tikz/output-figure files and how to how to control it

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

I am working on a `beamer` presentation that consists about 25 tikz and pgfplots graphics scattered all over the ~50 `frame`s.

Because of the multitude of `tikzpicture`s , I am using the `tikzexternalise` commands:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/,optimize command away=\pdfpages]
```

(the `pdfpages` exception is due to some inclusion of `pdf` files using `\includegraphics`)

together with  a `latemkrc` file that provides a command line switch:

```
$latex = 'pdftex -shell-escape main.tex %O %S';
```

pdfLaTeX then outputs files in ascending order with respect to their appearance in the `main.tex` file:

```
.
..
...
tikz/output-figure20.md5
tikz/output-figure20.pdf
tikz/output-figure21.dpth
tikz/output-figure21.md5
tikz/output-figure21.pdf
tikz/output-figure22.dpth
tikz/output-figure22.md5
tikz/output-figure22.pdf
tikz/output-figure23.log
etc.
```

What if during the writing progress of my presentation I decide to move one frame above the other? And completly delete one frame because I decide it is not relevant. Would it cause graphics to move too? How would it affect the use of already generated tikz outputs?

What is the correct workflow in such case?

Another question: Can I give names to those generated files so that it would be easier to keep track of their respective content? If yes, then how?

Can I redact the `*.md5`, `*.log`, `*.dpth` and `*.dep` files and keep only the `*.pdf* files?

I am afraid that this whole incorrect workflow I just described causes the error message

> Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape
> -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/output-figure23" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{output}\input{output}"' did NOT result in a
> usable output file 'tikz/output-figure23' (expected one of
> .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:).

which at the moment prevents me from going on working on my presentation.

Comment: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/758

Comment: @HenriMenke All right I think I understand the idea. Please correct me if I am wrong. Before every `\begin{figure}`, insert `\tikzsetnextfilename{<file name>}` where `<file name>` hopefully has a meaningful name, such as `barPlot05` or `scatter02`. I just tested it and it seems to be working on a sandbox project. But what about all the `*.md5`, `*.log`, `*.dpth` and `*.dep` files? Do I need to keep them?

Comment: @HenriMenke `"[...] because the code of the externalization library is mostly unreadable gibberish."` :) :) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Too long for a comment.*

---

As you have already written in [the comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597087/a-mess-of-tikz-output-figure-files-and-how-to-how-to-control-it#comment1497050_597087) I also recommend to use `\tikzsetnextfilename`, but you should write it directly before the `\tikz` command or the `\begin{tikzpicture}` environment. Then you also have a workflow if there is more than one TikZ environment in a figure environment.

Here some "random" code for the further discussion borrowed from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436405/95441.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        % use the one from PGFPlots which is more recent than the one from tikz
        pgfplots.external,
    }
    % put all externalized images in a "special" folder
    \tikzsetexternalprefix{Pics/pgf-export/}
    % enable externalization
    \tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
% (I prefer to give the images reasonable names)
\tikzsetnextfilename{first}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        xlabel={A},
        ylabel={B},
        legend to name=named,
    ]
        \addplot+ [domain=1:10] {x};
        \addlegendentry{$10\%$}
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzsetnextfilename{second}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        xlabel={A},
        ylabel={B},
    ]
        \addplot+ [domain=1:10] {1/x};
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

    % (you can also name this image, if you want to)
    \tikzsetnextfilename{first-legend}
    \pgfplotslegendfromname{named}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I store all the externalized files in a separate folder, which has the additional benefit that also all the auxiliary files which are created during externalization are stored in that folder. From that you can delete all files except

- non-zero `dep` files
- non-zero `dpth` files
- `md5` files
  (Hopefully I didn't miss anything. Otherwise please add a comment or directly edit the answer.)

To do so I have created a `bat` file (sorry, I am a Windows child) which is also located in the "externalize" folder. That I execute from time to time and looks like

```
REM pause
del *.acn
del *.log
del *.glo
del *.ist
del *.nlo
del *.xml

REM delete zero byte DPTH files
@echo off
for %%f in (*.dpth) do if %%~zf==0 del /F /Q "%%f"

REM delete zero byte DEP files
@echo off
for %%f in (*.dep) do if %%~zf==0 del /F /Q "%%f"
```

Feel free to adapt it to your needs.